# PHP - Display characters in Arabic?

Tags: php

The problem is the display of the Arabic language in php, with French and English it works well but in Arabic it only displays the: ???

this is a code 
`

```
// connexion 
$host="****";
$user="****";
$password="****";
$dbname="****";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname);
    $lang = trim($_GET['lang']);
    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

    $sql="SELECT title,image,rating,releaseYear,id,pays,language FROM user  WHERE  language='$lang' and pays='$rtt '   ORDER BY `user`.`id` DESC" ;   
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($result)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {            $flag[]=array('title'=>utf8_encode($row['title']),'image'=>$row['image'],'rating'=>utf8_encode($row['rating']),'releaseYear'=>$row['releaseYear'],'id'=>$row['id']);    
    }      
     print_r(json_encode($flag, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));     
} 
mysqli_close($con); 
?>`
```

this is a image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwyqQ.png)

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow must be in English.

Answer (score 0):

Did you verify your browser charset ?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

Comment: and your database collation is it defined to utf-8bin ?

Comment: i tried utf8-bin ,  utf_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci and it is the same